# Separate ng-message with comma separator

Tags: angularjs, css, css-selectors

I have angular validation message as follow.
I would like to display error message in a line, separated by comma and end with fullstop.

I try below but not working. Comma will be shown when there is only one error message.
Note that i am expecting pure css solution for this.

```
<div class="validation-error-message">
    <span ng-message="form.email.$error" role="alert">
        <span ng-message="email">Invalid email</span>
    <span>
    <span ng-message="form.password.$error" role="alert">
        <span ng-message="minlength">Password does not meet minlength</span>
    <span>
</div>
```

What i have tried:

```
.validation-error-message {
    span > span::after {
        content: ', '
    }

    span:last-child > span::after {
        content: '.'
    }
}
```

Sample expected outcome: 
Invalid email.
Password does not meet minlength.
Invalid email, Password does not meet minlength.

Answer (score 0):

You can try other way

```
.validation-error-message >span
{
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
```